# mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019:

Tags: c++, qt

-----------MyChatROOM.pro--------------------------------
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MyChatROOM
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -lwsock32

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

------mainwindow.h----------------------

## ifndef MAINWINDOW_H

## define MAINWINDOW_H

## include

## include "../ChatRoomServerr.h"

namespace Ui {

class MainWindow;

}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow

{

```
Q_OBJECT

ChatRoomServer server;
```

public:

```
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

~MainWindow();
```

private:

```
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
```

};

## endif // MAINWINDOW_H

----------------main.cpp-----------------

## include "mainwindow.h"

## include

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

MainWindow w;

w.show();



return a.exec();
```

}

----------mainwindow.cpp-----------

## include "mainwindow.h"

## include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :

```
QMainWindow(parent),

ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
```

{

```
ui->setupUi(this);

server.init();
```

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()

{

```
delete ui;

server.release();
```

}

---------------ChatRoomServerr.h------------

## ifndef _CHAT_ROOM_SERVER_H

## define _CHAT_ROOM_SERVER_H

## include

## include "../source/net_stream.h"

## include

## include

class ChatRoomServer

{

private:

```
NetListener listener;
```

public:

```
typedef std::list <NetStream> V_STREAM;

V_STREAM vStream;
```

public:

```
void init()

{

    listener.startListen(2345);

}



void doStream(NetStream& stream)

{

    stream.totalRecv();



    int pktID;

    while (stream.checkRecv(pktID))

    {

        if (pktID == PKT_STR)

        {

            char buf[256];

            stream.recv(buf, sizeof(buf));



            V_STREAM::iterator pi = vStream.begin();

            while (pi != vStream.end())

            {

                if (&(*pi) != &stream)

                    pi->send(buf);

                ++pi;

            }

        }

        else if (pktID == PKT_CHAR)

        {

            char chr;

            stream.recv(chr);




            V_STREAM::iterator pi = vStream.begin();

            while (pi != vStream.end())

            {

                if (&(*pi) != &stream)

                    pi->send(chr);

                ++pi;

            }



        }

        else

        {

            assert(0);

        }

    }



    stream.totalSend();

}



void work()

{

    while (listener.doAccept())

    {


        vStream.resize(vStream.size() + 1);



        listener.popAcceptSocket(vStream.back());

    }



    V_STREAM::iterator pi = vStream.begin();

    while (pi != vStream.end())

    {

        doStream(*pi);

        pi++;

    }

}



void release()

{

}
```

};

## endif

-----------------net_stream.h----------------------

## ifndef _NET_STREAM_H_

## define _NET_STREAM_H_

## include

## include

## include

## include

enum {PKT_CHAR, PKT_INT, PKT_FLOAT, PKT_XY,PKT_STR} ;

class NetStream

{

private:

```
SOCKET newSocket ;

bool bConnected ;



typedef std::vector <char> V_SEND_DATA ;

V_SEND_DATA vSendData ;

int curSendPos ;

V_SEND_DATA vRecvData ;

int curRecvPos ;

int curDataSize;
```

public:

```
NetStream ():bConnected(false),newSocket(INVALID_SOCKET),curRecvPos(0)

{

}



~NetStream ()

{

    close () ;

}



static void fnInit ()

{

    WSADATA wsaData;

    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2) ;

    WSAStartup (version, &wsaData) ;

}



static void fnRelease ()

{

    WSACleanup () ;

}



bool isConnected ()const

{

    return bConnected ;

}



void setAcceptSocket (SOCKET as)

{

    close () ;



    assert (newSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) ;

    newSocket = as ;




    u_long nonBlock = true ;

    int r = ioctlsocket (newSocket, 

                FIONBIO, &nonBlock) ;

    assert (r != SOCKET_ERROR) ;



    bConnected = true ;

}



void startConnect (const char* ip, int port)

{

    close () ;



    assert (newSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) ;




    newSocket = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 

                        IPPROTO_TCP) ;

    assert (newSocket != INVALID_SOCKET) ;



    int i0, i1, i2, i3 ;

    sscanf (ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &i0, &i1, &i2, &i3) ;



    sockaddr_in connectAddress ;

    memset (&connectAddress, 0, sizeof

                    (connectAddress)) ;

    connectAddress.sin_family = AF_INET ;

    connectAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 = i0 ;

    connectAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 = i1 ;

    connectAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 = i2 ;

    connectAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4 = i3 ;

    connectAddress.sin_port = htons (port) ;



    //設定non block mode

    u_long nonBlock = true ;

    int r = ioctlsocket (newSocket, FIONBIO, &nonBlock) ;

    assert (r != SOCKET_ERROR) ;




    r = connect (newSocket, (sockaddr*)&connectAddress, 

            sizeof (connectAddress)) ;

}



void checkConnected ()

{

    if (newSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)

        if (bConnected == false)

        {

            fd_set tmpSet ;

            FD_ZERO(&tmpSet); 

            FD_SET(newSocket,&tmpSet); 



            timeval timeV ;

            timeV.tv_sec = 0 ;

            timeV.tv_usec = 100 ;

            if (select (0, NULL, &tmpSet, NULL, &timeV) == 1)

            {

                bConnected = true ;

            }

        }

}
```

private:

```
void sendBuf (const void* pData, int dataSize)

{




    int oriSize = vSendData.size () ;

    vSendData.resize (oriSize+dataSize) ;



    const char* pSD = (const char*)pData ;

    for (int i = 0; i<dataSize; i++)

        vSendData[oriSize+i] = pSD[i] ;

}
```

public:

```
void totalSend ()

{

    if (isConnected () && vSendData.size () > 0)

    {

        const char* pData = &(vSendData[0]) ;

        int dataSize = vSendData.size () ;



        int r = ::send (newSocket, pData, dataSize, 0) ;



        if (r != SOCKET_ERROR)

        {

            if (r < dataSize)

            {


                int leftSize = dataSize-r ;

                for (int i = 0; i<leftSize; i++)

                    vSendData[i] = vSendData[i+r] ;

                vSendData.resize (leftSize) ;

            }else

            {


                vSendData.clear () ;

            }

        }else

        {

            r = WSAGetLastError () ;

            if (r == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)

            {


            }else

            {


                close () ;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

private:

```
void beginSendBuf (int pktID)

{

    curSendPos = vSendData.size () ;



    int fakeSize = -1 ;

    sendBuf (&fakeSize, sizeof (fakeSize)) ;



    sendBuf (&pktID, sizeof (pktID)) ;

}



void endSendBuf ()

{

    int pktSize = vSendData.size ()-curSendPos ;

    int* pSize = (int*)(&(vSendData[curSendPos])) ;

    *pSize = pktSize ;

}
```

public:

```
void send(const char* chr)

{

    if (isConnected())

    {

        beginSendBuf(PKT_STR);




        sendBuf(chr,strlen(chr));



        endSendBuf();

    }

}



void send (const char& data)

{

    if (isConnected ())

    {

        beginSendBuf (PKT_CHAR) ;




        sendBuf (&data, sizeof (data)) ;



        endSendBuf () ;

    }

}



void send (const int& data)

{

    if (isConnected ())

    {

        beginSendBuf (PKT_INT) ;




        sendBuf (&data, sizeof (data)) ;



        endSendBuf () ;

    }

}



void send (const float& data)//送float

{

    if (isConnected ())

    {

        beginSendBuf (PKT_FLOAT) ;




        sendBuf (&data, sizeof (data)) ;



        endSendBuf () ;

    }

}



void sendXY (const float& x, const float& y)

{

    if (isConnected ())

    {

        beginSendBuf (PKT_XY) ;



        //真正的資料

        sendBuf (&x, sizeof (x)) ;

        sendBuf (&y, sizeof (y)) ;



        endSendBuf () ;

    }

}



void totalRecv ()

{

    if (isConnected () == false)

        return ;



    if (curRecvPos > 0)

    {

        int leftSize = vRecvData.size ()-curRecvPos ;



        for (int i = 0; i<leftSize; i++)

            vRecvData[i] = vRecvData[curRecvPos+i] ;



        vRecvData.resize (leftSize) ;



        curRecvPos = 0 ;

    }



    while (true)

    {

        int oriSize = vRecvData.size () ;

        const int TMP_RECV_SIZE = 1024*10 ;

        vRecvData.resize (oriSize+TMP_RECV_SIZE) ;

        char* pData = &(vRecvData[oriSize]) ;



        int recvSize = ::recv (newSocket, pData, TMP_RECV_SIZE, 0) ;

        if (recvSize > 0)

        {

            //有收到資料

            if (recvSize < TMP_RECV_SIZE)

            {


                int extSize = TMP_RECV_SIZE-recvSize ;

                vRecvData.resize (vRecvData.size ()-extSize) ;

                break ;

            }else

            {


            }

        }else if (recvSize == 0)

        {

            //斷線了

            close () ;

            break ;

        }else

        {

            vRecvData.resize (vRecvData.size ()-TMP_RECV_SIZE) ;



            int r = WSAGetLastError () ;

            if (r == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)

            {


            }else

            {


                close () ;

            }

            break ;

        }

    }

}



bool checkRecv (int &pktID)

{

    int totalSize = vRecvData.size ()-curRecvPos ;

    int recvSize = sizeof (int)+sizeof (int) ;//大小+ID

    if (totalSize >= recvSize)

    {

        //可以取得pktSize+pktID

        int* pData = (int*)(&(vRecvData[curRecvPos])) ;

        int pktSize = *pData ;

        curDataSize = pktSize - sizeof(int) - sizeof(int);



        if (totalSize >= pktSize)

        {


            pData  = (int*)(&(vRecvData[curRecvPos+sizeof (int)])) ;

            pktID = *pData ;



            curRecvPos += recvSize ;

            return true ;

        }else

        {


            return false ;

        }

    }else

    {


        return false ;

    }

}

bool recv(char *buf, int bufSize)

{

    int totalSize = vRecvData.size() - curRecvPos;

    assert(bufSize >= curDataSize+1);

    if (totalSize >= curDataSize)

    {//資料足夠

        char* pData = (char *)(&vRecvData[curRecvPos]);

        for (int i = 0; i < curDataSize; i++)

            buf[i] = pData[i];

        buf[curDataSize] = 0;

        curRecvPos += curDataSize;

        return true;

    }

    else

        assert(0);

    return false;

}

bool recv (char &data)

{

    int totalSize = vRecvData.size ()-curRecvPos ;
    int recvSize = sizeof (data) ;

    if (totalSize >= recvSize)

    {

        //資料足夠

        char* pData = (char*)(&(vRecvData[curRecvPos])) ;

        data = *pData ;



        curRecvPos += recvSize ;

        return true ;

    }else

    {

        //資料不夠

        assert(0);

        return false ;

    }

}



bool recv (int &data)

{

    int totalSize = vRecvData.size ()-curRecvPos ;//有效資料的大小

    int recvSize = sizeof (data) ;

    if (totalSize >= recvSize)

    {


        int* pData = (int*)(&(vRecvData[curRecvPos])) ;

        data = *pData ;



        curRecvPos += recvSize ;

        return true ;

    }else

    {


        assert(0);

        return false ;

    }

}



bool recv (float &data)

{

    int totalSize = vRecvData.size ()-curRecvPos ;//有效資料的大小

    int recvSize = sizeof (data) ;

    if (totalSize >= recvSize)

    {

        float* pData = (float*)(&(vRecvData[curRecvPos])) ;

        data = *pData ;



        curRecvPos += recvSize ;

        return true ;

    }else

    {

        assert(0);

        return false ;

    }

}



bool recvXY (float &x, float& y)

{

    int totalSize = vRecvData.size ()-curRecvPos ;

    int recvSize = sizeof (x)+sizeof (y) ;

    if (totalSize >= recvSize)

    {



        float* pData = (float*)(&(vRecvData[curRecvPos])) ;

        x = *pData ;



        pData = (float*)(&(vRecvData[curRecvPos+sizeof (x)])) ;

        y = *pData ;



        curRecvPos += recvSize ;

        return true ;

    }else

    {

        assert(0);

        return false ;

    }

}



void close ()

{

    if (newSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)

    {

        closesocket (newSocket) ;

        newSocket = INVALID_SOCKET ;

        bConnected = false ;

        curRecvPos = 0 ;

    }

}
```

} ;

## include

class NetListener

{

private:

```
SOCKET skt ;



typedef std::vector <SOCKET> V_ACCEPT_SOCKET ;

V_ACCEPT_SOCKET vAcceptSocket ;
```

public:

```
void startListen (int port)

{

    skt = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 

                                IPPROTO_TCP) ;

    assert (skt != INVALID_SOCKET) ;


    u_long nonBlock = true ;

    int r = ioctlsocket (skt, FIONBIO, &nonBlock) ;

    assert (r != SOCKET_ERROR) ;



    sockaddr_in serverAddress ;

    memset (&serverAddress, 0, sizeof (serverAddress)) ;

    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET ;

    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY ;

    serverAddress.sin_port = htons (port) ;



    r = bind (skt, (sockaddr*)&serverAddress, 

                sizeof (serverAddress)) ;

    assert (r != SOCKET_ERROR) ;




    r = listen (skt, SOMAXCONN) ;

    assert (r != SOCKET_ERROR) ;

}







bool doAccept ()

{

    while (true)

    {

        SOCKET newSocket = accept (skt, NULL, NULL) ;

        if (newSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)

        {

            vAcceptSocket.push_back (newSocket) ;

        }else

            break ;

    }



    if (vAcceptSocket.size () > 0)

        return true ;

    else

        return false ;

}



void popAcceptSocket (NetStream& ns)

{

    assert (vAcceptSocket.size () > 0) ;



    ns.setAcceptSocket (vAcceptSocket.front ()) ;





    vAcceptSocket.erase (vAcceptSocket.begin ()) ;//刪除

}



/*

bool acceptStream (NetStream& ns)

{

    SOCKET newSocket = accept (skt, NULL, NULL) ;

    if (newSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)

    {

        ns.setAcceptSocket (newSocket) ;

        return true ;

    }else

        return false ;

}

*/
```

} ;

## endif

Comment: Colud someone can help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Replace tabs with spaces.  Then highlight the code sections and click on the "{}" button.  This should fix your formatting problem.

Comment: Could you help us by using a *debugger* and executing each statement one at a time?  *Watch* the values of variables.  Modify your post to indicate the statement that is causing the issue and also remove any code that is not relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolved external symbols - Qt creator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069041/unresolved-external-symbols-qt-creator)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry!!I resolved it.
After reinstall Qt,this problem is not appear again!
Maybe MainGW was not install before.